# Efficient way of merging ranges (intervals) within a given threshold

Tags: python, algorithm, pandas, merge, biopython

I'd like to know if there is an efficient way of computing ranges distance and combine them for a given distance. For example, given ranges and distance of *d=10*:

```
1   2
4   7
12  15
32  36
38  41
...
```

First iteration would be: *(4-2) -> 2 -> 2 < 10 -> OK -> (1,7)*

```
1   7
12  15
32  36
38  41
...
```

*(12-7) -> 5 -> 5 < 10 -> OK -> (1,15)*

```
1   15
32  36
38  41
...
```

*(32-15) -> 17 -> 17 < 10 -> KO*

```
1   15
32  36
38  41
...
```

*(38-36) -> 2 -> 2 < 10 -> OK -> (32,41)*

**Desired** (resulting) data set:

```
1   15
32  41
...
```

Cost of this algorithm (lists, tuples, loops) could put in risk the main program if its not implemented efficiently.

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: how is the original data stored? Is it a 2D-list?

Comment: No, it is a dataframe of three columns (name, range_ini, range_end) but I can adapt it to the algorithm input

Comment: Have you tried something and run into efficiency problems?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Source DF:

```
In [27]: df
Out[27]:
   start  end
0      1    2
1      4    7
2     12   15
3     32   36
4     38   41

In [28]: threshold = 10
```

Vectorized solution:

```
In [31]: (df.groupby(df['start'].sub(df['end'].shift()).ge(threshold).cumsum())
    ...:    .agg({'start':'first','end':'last'}))
    ...:
Out[31]:
   start  end
0      1   15
1     32   41
```

Explanation:

```
In [32]: df['start'].sub(df['end'].shift())
Out[32]:
0     NaN
1     2.0
2     5.0
3    17.0
4     2.0
dtype: float64

In [33]: df['start'].sub(df['end'].shift()).ge(threshold)
Out[33]:
0    False
1    False
2    False
3     True
4    False
dtype: bool

In [34]: df['start'].sub(df['end'].shift()).ge(threshold).cumsum()
Out[34]:
0    0
1    0
2    0
3    1
4    1
dtype: int32
```

Comment: Hello! Thank you! It seems works! I'm gonna check it with a large file. Does it work for a three columns anyway??

Comment: @Solar, three columns? Can you provide a small reproducible data set?

Comment: Hello again, don't worry! I can handle it anyway. I'm gonna check it!

Comment: @Solar, i think you'll need to apply one of the aggregation functions (first, last, min, max, etc.) onto `name` column